# ValueError: could not convert string to float: python error

Tags: python

so heres my code , when i run i get the error after i open the anaconda prompt. i even converted the temps to float but its still not working after i open aaconda

```
temp1 = (input())
temp2 = (input())
temp3 = (input())
new_temp1=float(temp1)
new_temp2=float(temp2)
new_temp3=float(temp3)
Avg = (new_temp1 + new_temp2 + new_temp3)/3
x=round(Avg)
NO_ERROR=((new_temp1>-10 and new_temp1<40) and (new_temp2>-10 and new_temp2<40) and (new_temp3>-10 
and new_temp3<40))
ERROR=((new_temp1>-10 or new_temp1<40) or (new_temp2>-10 or new_temp2<40) or (new_temp3>-10 or new_temp3<40))
print ((NO_ERROR==True and "NO ERROR") or (ERROR==True and "ERROR"))
print (f"Avg: {Avg:.2f}")
print (f"Rounded Avg: {x}")
```

Comment: What is the input that you are typing?

Comment: im typing temperature and the code is supposed to print average and check some conditions without using if statement

Comment: what did you type?

Comment: any value between -10-100

Comment: Are you sure that, they are floats?

Comment: yes , pretty sure i used the code and it worked fine with float values , also used %whos function

Comment: You don't need parenthesis around `input()`